# ag grid copy selected rows data formatted via valueFormatter in context menu

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

can someone help how to copy row data with formatted grid values in right click menu options

Grid column defs have valueFormatter

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the help of processCellForClipboard(params) as mentioned in documentation

Answer (score 0):

You have to process each cell manually like this:

```js
  function prepareCellForClipboard(params) {
    // Export values as formatted
    const colDef = params.column.getColDef()
    if (colDef.valueFormatter) {
      return colDef.valueFormatter({
        ...params,
        data: params.node?.data,
        colDef: colDef,
      })
    }
    return params.value
  }

  const gridOptions: GridOptions = { ...agGridDefaultOptions }
  gridOptions.processCellForClipboard = prepareCellForClipboard
```